# Fatal error al generar un excel con PHPExcel y SQL... "Call to a member function query() on a non-object.."

Tags: php, sql, phpexcel

Mi problema en concreto es que debo generar un excel[.xlsx] (uso PHPExcel) con datos desde SQL Server con PHP.

El script que edito ya existía con sentencias MySQL y funcionaba perfectamente, pero al cambiar las sentencias por SQL me genera el siguiente error:

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function *query()* on a non-object in C:\..."

Y el código en resumen es:

```
$query_Data="select * from etc etc etc";

$connectionInfo1 = array( "Database"=>xxx, "UID"=>yyy, "PWD"=>zzz);
$conexion = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo1);

$resultado = $conexion->query($query_Data); [el error que funcionaba con mysql]
(cualquier sentencia que reemplace a query() me genera error)
```

Nota: No sé si tenga que ver que el método de llamado de conexión es distinto en MySQL (que si sirve) al de SQL (que no sirve.)

Agradezco me puedan colaborar con información de como puedo solucionar ese "Fatal error", de antemano mil gracias!

Comment: Creo que tu sentencia debería ir luego de donde realizas la conexión a la base de datos!

Comment: Así está en el script original pero aun sigue sin funcionar, gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: revisa la variable $serverName

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que la función que llamas sql_srv_connect esta dando un error de conexión, si lees la documentación (http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) retorna falso cuando existe algún problema, por eso da ese error de función no encontrada.

Para saber el error tienes que llamar a sqlsrv_errors(), esto te da el problema.

algo así:

```
$conexion = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo1);

if( $conexion ) {
     // hace la consulta
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, con 'sqlsrv_errors()' es que me pude dar cuenta del error "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\..." el cual aun persiste.

Comment: uhmmm, 'sqlsrv_errors()' no te puede dar ese error, ya que esa función retorna errores que da la base de datos y el que comentas en claramente un eror de PHP.

En el ejemplo 1 de la documentación oficial (http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-errors.php) hay una forma de pintar los errores y te da una idea de su estructura.